# Is there any way to set the priority of a process in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, process, priority

I have a background process running at 100% CPU on Mac OS X. All other applications are very slow because of it.

I'd like to set this process to take no more than 50% so that my applications can run better. How can I do this?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

From the command line (`Terminal.app` or whatever) use `nice` and `renice`, just like on other unixes.

Use `nice` when launching a process:

```
nice -n <priority> <command> <arguments to command>
```

The default priority is zero, positive values are "nicer" (that is lower priority) and negative values are "less nice" (higher priority). Looks like Mac OS runs from +10 to -10.

Use `renice` to change the priority of a process already running (from the `renice` man page on 10.5):

```
renice priority [[-p] pid ...] [[-g] pgrp ...] [[-u] user ...]  
renice -n increment [[-p] pid ...] [[-g] pgrp ...] [[-u] user ...]
```

The part you're interested in here is the `pid` bit. That is the process id for the job and you can find it using `ps -u <your username>` and looking for the process name, but I prefer `top -o` in this case, because the process you're interested in will be near the top.

**Note:** Without superuser privileges you can never increase a process's priority. For normal users, `nice` and `renice` are one way streets. And small changes in priority can have large effects on running time. So go easy on this until you understand it.

Comment: And how can I do with an already running process? It's running for 2 hours and I don't want to start it again and loose my 2 hours of processing

Comment: From the man page on MacOS 12.6: "nice runs utility at an altered scheduling priority.  If an increment is given, it is used; otherwise an increment of 10 is assumed.  The super-user can run utilities with priorities higher than normal by using a negative increment.  The priority can be adjusted over a range of -20 (the highest) to 20 (the lowest)"

Answer (score 23):

You can use the command:

```
renice -n # PID
```

Where:

- *#* is a number that should be larger than 0 (otherwise you will move your process to higher priority)
- *PID* is the process ID you can view by typing `top` on the terminal app (utilities/terminal.app)

If it is a system process or another user process you should type:

```
sudo renice -n 10 PID
```

It will ask you for your password (if you are sudoer). As for the number I would recommend 10 or 19 (even lower priority).

Note that this will change the priority not the CPU usage. If you aren't running other processes which require CPU or you have more than one CPU on your Mac (Core 2 Quad Core) the process might still use 100% of CPU.

Answer (score 10):

```
renice 20 $(pgrep ImageOptim)
```

Or use the name of your program instead of ImageOptim

Comment: Additionally, using `renice -20` gives a process the highest possible priority, for example when compiling a big program like octave. `renice 20` gives a process the lowest priority.

Answer (score 8):

- If your process is an app or app helper utility rather than a system process and you don't want to do `nice` or `renice` on every system boot you can give it a shot to [AppPolice](https://github.com/fuyu/AppPolice).
  It's open source and free. You can download it [here](https://github.com/fuyu/AppPolice/releases), or install it with the [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) command `brew cask install AppPolice`
- If you want to change a running process or service or app's macOS alloted CPU-thread resources, and also change scheduling priority by applying the `renice` on running process via GUI tool, then you may try [CPUSetter](https://www.WhatRoute.net/cpusetter.html). Its not open-source though, but works in newer macOS (tested on macOS Monterey v12.6.1), and cost-free. It is a voluntary donation-ware.
- Another alternative would be a very nice command line task manager GUI called `htop`. You can see all the processes and tune their `nice` values by `F7` and and `F8` shortcuts.
  *(Please note that negative `nice` values are more prioritized and opposite for positive values)*

  - To install it:

    - Install package-manager, such as: [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) or [MacPorts](https://www.MacPorts.org/), if you don't have it yet.
    - In Terminal, run below command, based on what pkg-mgr you installed:

      - if you installed `homebrew` pkg-mgr, run`:` `brew install htop`
      - if you installed `MacPorts` pkg-mgr, run`:` `sudo port install htop`
  - Now you can do `htop` to see and manage processes in Terminal or `sudo htop` to cover all the system.

Careful when you set scheduling-priority value with `nice` or `renice` tool/function:

- positive value from 1 to 20, reduces priority. the `20` or `+20` is lowest priority.
- negative value from -1 to -20, increases priority. the `-20` is highest priority.
- the 0 is default / normal / general priority setting.
- depending on macOS settings, privileged user can set negative values (aka: higher priority) and also positive values (aka: lower priority), and regular user may be allowed to only set positive values (aka: lower-priority), in order to not-override privileged user's settings, for certain apps or globally.

Answer (score 6):

There are also a number of GUI utilities, like the free BeNicer and [Process Wizard](http://www.lachoseinteractive.net/en/products/processwizard/) (my previous favorite), and the $1.99 version of [Freezer](http://mrgeckosmedia.com/applications/info/Freezer), which is my new favorite. These all work on running applications.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that BeNicer and Process Wizard only run on PowerPC processors, so they won't run at all on any Mac which Apple currently supports. Freezer works, but for me it seems to only work for apps that show up in the Dock, not Menu Bar apps like _Backup and Sync from Google_

Answer (score 1):

You can set the nice value (priority) for the daemon permanently using the variable in the PLIST file for the app. To find out how type MAN plist in a terminal window.