# Is There A CPU Process Limiter For Mac OS X?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

I am having trouble with some processed which hog up all the CPU power such as flash.

Is there a GUI app which can limit how much each process can use the CPU? I know you can do this via command line, but I would like something more user friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Freezer](http://mrgeckosmedia.com/applications/info/Freezer).  Thanks to [beiju](https://superuser.com/users/11773/beiju) for finding these [for his own answer](https://superuser.com/questions/42817/is-there-any-way-to-set-the-priority-of-a-process-in-mac-os-x/44074#44074).

Comment: I'm running snow leopard, all those mentioned are either very very very old and do not specify support, or say they don't support.

Comment: The publisher of Freezer commented on that page that Snow Leopard is supported. I tested it on SL just now and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Freezer does not allow me to 'limit' how much a process takes from the CPU. It only allows me to pause, and change priority, but not set for example 10% for a particular process. Also it only lists the opened applications, it does not allow me to target for example 'Flash Player (Safari Internet plug-in), and other background processes.

Comment: I see. I didn't know such a thing was possible. For my own knowledge, what command line does that (you referred to it in the question)?

Comment: I tried the apps you suggested, but they made no difference on CPU usage. Command line that does such (I think): http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Ah, that program is doing busywork trickery to make it happen. Interesting, though. Thanks for the info.  Out of curiosity, why do you need to limit to a certain percentage? Why not let it consume 100% if it's uncontested, and use renice to make it throttle back if other program want the CPU?

Comment: Sorry, I tried 'Process Wizard' again, and worked out I was limiting the wrong process, had to double check the pid, after doing it, flash and safari went from 50% to 10% CPU usage!!!!! Finally, A wasy to put flash and safari BACK INTO LINE! ahhahaha thanks a billion!

Comment: Using macbook pro, 50%-100% CPU usage makes the fans go nuts