# Prevent important OS X process being swapped out, without code change?

Tags: macos, memory, swap, memory-management

I want hotkey-based utilities like Quicksilver or Zooom to respond immediately.  But if they have been idle for a while, they (I guess) get swapped out, and respond slowly, sometimes not even responding to the first few keystrokes I wanted to send to them.

How can I encourage such processes (i.e. chosen processes, not all processes system wide) to remain in active memory?  Or, am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: Maybe just get more RAM?

Comment: I have 8G, which is the max possible.  It's sufficient for reasonable app responsiveness, but for things like Quickeys and Zooom, I don't want "reasonable"---I want "instant".

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can change memory management policy on userland easily. Your best bet is to [raise the priority of the process](https://superuser.com/questions/285355/how-to-permanently-renice-a-process-on-mac-os-x-or-ios-etc).